# Add category when I create a product on PrestaShop

Tags: php, model-view-controller, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am creating an import module products on PrestaShop 1.6. the product is created without problems but the categories are not included.

I used:

```
$product->id_category = array();
foreach($arr_cat_full as $cat){                          
    $category = Category::searchByName(1, trim($cat), true);
    $product->id_category[] = (int)$category['id_category'];                       
}
```

If I enter:

```
var_dump($category['id_category']);
```

The result is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `addToCategories($categories = array())` function of `Product` class.

to use in this way:

```
$array_cc = array();
$product->id_category = array();
foreach($arr_cat_full as $cat){                          
        $category = Category::searchByName(1, trim($cat), true);
        $array_cc = (int)$category['id_category'];                       
}

$product->add();
$product->addToCategories($array_cc);
```

Good luck.